# Глубокое копирование объекта без использования рекурсии, JSON.parse \ stringify, structuredClone()

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Как реализовать глубокое копирование без использования рекурсии, JSON.parse, JSON.stringify, structuredClone(), lodash и другие готовые решения. Необходимо реализовать свой собственный алгоритм. Глубина дерева может очень глубокой, типы данных в значениях могут быть разные.

```
const data1 = {
  a: 10,
  y: null,
  k: [1, 2],
  b: 3,
  c: {
    d: 4,
    e: {
      w: 50,
      u: undefined,
      s: {
        f: {
          v: 5,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const data2 = [
{
  a: 10,
  y: null,
  k: [1, 2],
  b: 3,
  c: {
    d: 4,
    e: {
      w: 50,
      u: undefined,
      s: {
        f: {
          v: 5,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
];
```

В моем примере не получается пройтись по всем ключам, я останавливаюсь на втором цикле.

```
function deepCopy(dataType) {
  const copy = {};
  let data = dataType;

  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    data = dataType[0];
  }

  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
      copy[key] = Array.isArray(data[key]) ? [] : value;
      for (let deepKey in data[key]) {
        copy[key][deepKey] = data[key][deepKey];
      }
    } else {
      copy[key] = data[key];
    }
  }
  return copy;
}
```

Можем ли мы реализовать данный алгоритм используя стек ?

Comment: Теория гласит что любую рекурсию можно сделать без рекурсии. Так что конечно можем, непонятно только зачем.

Comment: Если глубина дерева не известна, а рекурсию использовать нельзя, то глубину придется ограничить и для каждой глублины дублировать все обработчики. Я пока смутно представляю, как это можно сделать для неограниченного количества вложений.

Comment: @SwaD созданием собственного «стека вызовов».

Answer (score 1):

Что бы упростить решение, создадим объект `object` сразу, а в стек поместим записи `[object, key, value]`, каждая из которых означает: обработай значение `value` и помести его в `object[key]`.
Обработка состоит в определении типа объекта - скаляр, массив или словарь. Скаляры записываются по адресу без изменений. Для массивов и словарей по адресу записываются пустые контейнеры, а все их будущие элементы кладутся в стек.

Очередь подошла бы лучше чем стек, но в языке нет нормальной очереди. А так как у нас стек, обратите внимание на то что ключи словарей кладутся в стек задом наперёд. Иначе стек вставит ключи в обратном порядке. Формально этот будет тот же словарь, но выглядит это плохо. Поэтому `reverse()`. Для массива этот трюк не нужен, массив всегда перебирается по увеличению индексов. Цикл по массиву разреженный. Если массив был с пропусками, его копия будет такой же.

Обратите внимание что клоны объектов верхнего уровня создаются сразу, а затем редактируются задним числом. Это не соответствует естественному рекурсивному решению, не является его механическим переводом, но так итеративный код проще.

```js
const kindOf = v => {
    if (
        v === null ||
        v === undefined ||
        [
            'bigint',
            'boolean',
            'function',
            'number',
            'string',
            'symbol'
        ].includes(typeof v)
    ) {
        return 'scalar';
    }
    return (Array.isArray(v)) ? 'array' : 'object';
};

const clone = value => {
    const result = [];
    const stack = [[result, 0, value]];
    while (stack.length > 0) {
        let clone;
        const [target, key, value] = stack.pop();
        switch (kindOf(value)) {
        case 'scalar':
            clone = value;
            break;
        case 'array':
            clone = [];
            value.forEach((item, index) =>
                stack.push([clone, index, item])
            );
            break;
        case 'object':
            clone = {};
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(value).reverse()) {
                stack.push([clone, k, v])
            }
            break;
        }
        target[key] = clone;
    }
    return result[0];
};

console.log(clone({
  a: 10,
  y: null,
  k: [1, 2],
  b: 3,
  c: {
    d: 4,
    e: { w: 50, u: undefined, s: { f: { v: 5 } } }
  }
}));

console.log(clone([{
  a: 10,
  y: null,
  k: [1, 2],
  b: 3,
  c: {
    d: 4,
    e: { w: 50, u: undefined, s: { f: { v: 5 } } }
  }
}]));
```